# Transpose of a row vector in Octave causing problems with string escape character

Tags: sublimetext2, octave

In Sublime, I'm trying to take the transpose of a row vector in an Octave file as such:

```
y = [4, 5, 6];
y_transpose = y';
```

But whenever I try to run this in Octave, it acts as if introduction of the transpose operator (the ') is the beginning of a string, and ignores the following lines of code. How can I remedy this?

Comment: I just tested this on my version of Octave. It worked. Maybe you should check the version. Mine is 3.8.2. But either way, glad I could solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why it isn't working. `'` is actually listed as an operator in the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Arithmetic-Ops.html). But as a workaround, you could use the `transpose` function.

```
y = [4, 5, 6];
y_transpose = transpose(y);
```

Though I should note that `'` is the complex conjugate transpose. Normal transpose is `.'`. So maybe you should try:

```
y = [4, 5, 6];
y_transpose = y.';
```