# Output Orientation (Horizontal to Vertical) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, output

The following Matlab code works but I want the output to be in column format rather than row format. Ultimately, I would like Matlab to output a table at the end. It will be an iteration history of variables a b n dt i t(i) y(i)

How to do?

```
% Euler Method dy/dt=f(t,y)=sin(t^2)*sqrt(y)
f=@(t,y)(sin(t^2)*sqrt(y))
t(1)=1;
y(1)=1;
a=1;
b=3;
n=10;
dt=(b-a)/n;

for i=1:1:n
y(i+1)=y(i)+f(t(i),y(i))
t(i+1)=t(i)+dt;
end

I want to transpose the output (horizontal to vertical columns of t and y                        
side by side as opposed to a long column of t concatenated by y below.

[t y]' does the latter.
```

Thanks. MM

Comment: maybe you meant `[t y]'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose of a row vector in Octave causing problems with string escape character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873171/transpose-of-a-row-vector-in-octave-causing-problems-with-string-escape-characte)

Comment: then perhaps you meant `[t; y]'`